# Plotting .netCDF data correctly, impossible in Python (Basemap, Cartopy)

Tags: python, netcdf, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

I have been using .netCDF files (satellite data) for a few weeks now, and in general, I never had issues plotting them. I've been experimenting with sea ice concentration data but I can't get them right. As far as I can tell, the problem has to do something with the longitude/latitude being in meters. Nothing works right. Data seem to be rotated or falsely projected. The EPSG is 3411. I usually plot with `cartopy` but I decided to use `Basemap` also. None of them got the job done with my code. File can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KNcLKFKdvGQrN-tapZyX5PQSYGApPG8y/view).

```
import os
import xarray as xr
import cartopy.crs as ccrs 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
from pyproj import Transformer

data = xr.open_dataset('df.nc')
sea_ice = data.F17_ICECON; sea_ice

lons = data.x
lats = data.y
lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)

# Also experimented with this but without any results
transformer = Transformer.from_crs("EPSG:3411", "EPSG:4326")
lon_T, lat_T = transformer.transform(lon, lat)

# With Basemap
m = Basemap(width=6000000,height=6000000,
            resolution='l',projection='stere',lat_0=90,lon_0=0, epsg=3411)

m.pcolormesh(lon, lat, sea_ice[2])
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents(color='grey')

# With Cartopy
day = 4
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.contourf(lons, lats, sea_ice[day],
             transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.coastlines()

plt.show()
```

This is the image produced with [Basemap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDxEa.png) and this is with [Cartopy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwsse.png). Actual data should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9sZ0.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Cartopy with appropriate projection and get the plot. The projection I use is for plotting/visualization purposes only, as it is not exact equal EPSG:3411.

```
import xarray as xr
import cartopy.crs as ccrs 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = xr.open_dataset('df.nc')
sea_ice = data.F17_ICECON

lons = data.x
lats = data.y
lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)

fig = plt.figure(111, figsize=[8,8])

# Use this projection instead of the one that fails
useproj = ccrs.NorthPolarStereo(central_longitude=-45,true_scale_latitude=70)
ax = plt.subplot(projection=useproj)
day = 4
ax.contourf(lons, lats, sea_ice[day])
ax.coastlines(alpha=0.5, lw=0.3)
gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)

plt.show()
```

[image: npolarplot]